Parameters to every compose
Using Jetpack Compose I need to pass a lot of parameters to each compose, like navController.
MainScreen(navController) -> Child1(navController) -> Chil1OfChild1(navController).
Is that what I see in the documentation. But there's a better way? CompositionLocalProvider is a good alternative?

Yes. Composition locals were designed to solve this problem.
